# Getting Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' when using env variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm not sure if any of you ever came across the same issue but I've got a problem with `ts-node` and environment variables and your help would be much appreciated!

What I'm trying to do here is basically just to run `index.ts` with `ts-node`. And this `index.ts` simply prints out one of the environment variables.

**index.ts:**

```
import "dotenv/config";

const printEnv = (value: string) => {
  console.log(value);
};

printEnv(process.env.PASSWORD);
```

To make the environment variables available from `index.ts`, I created `env.d.ts` in which I defined the type of the variable.

**env.d.ts:**

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      PASSWORD: string;
    }
  }
}
export {}
```

I set up my `tsconfig.json`, `package.json` and `.env` files like below.

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ts-env",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1"
  }
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ts-env",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1"
  }
}
```

**.env:**

```
PASSWORD=test0123
```

With this setup, Visual Studio Code is now able to show me the possible options whenever I type `process.env.`

[image]

But it fails to compile whenever I try to run this application with `ts-node`, saying that `process.env.PASSWORD` could be undefined.

Here is the error log from `ts-node`:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:9:10 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

9 printEnv(process.env.PASSWORD);
```

I did fair amount of digging but unable to find a right solution for this issue. It would be much appreciated if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type for an environment variable is `string | undefined`, which makes sense because it can miss, either the entire `.env` file, or just that the variable is not in it.

The fix here is either to change your function definition to:

```
const printEnv = (value: string | undefined) => {
  console.log(value);
};

printEnv(process.env.PASSWORD);
```

Or tell TypeScript that the variable `PASSWORD` exist for sure with the `!` mark, like so:

```
const printEnv = (value: string) => {
  console.log(value);
};

printEnv(process.env.PASSWORD!);
```