# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' in Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

I stored a value in `process.ENV.VARIABLE`. When I try to use this value in my Playwright test as follows:

```
await page.getByPlaceholder('Filter').fill(process.ENV.VARIABLE);
```

it gives following error:

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

When I do a `console.log` it shows the value. I also tried the following but that returns undefined:

```
let employeeName:string = ${process.env.VARIABLE};

console.log("Employee name : " + employeeName);// returns undefined
```

Comment: Any given environment variable _could_ not be set at runtime, hence they're all typed as `string | undefined`. Your code needs to deal with that possibility.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' when using env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191318/getting-argument-of-type-string-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your env variable might be `undefined` while the function expects just a `string`, to which `undefined` is not acceptable:

```
const case1: string | undefined = undefined; // no error
const case2: string = undefined; // error
```

There are a couple of options here:

1. [non null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-):

   By using this operator in your case you are ensuring that the variable will definitely have the `string` value:

   ```
   const str: string = process.env.ENV_VAR! // no error
   ```
2. Checking the existence before the usage:

   ```
   const envVar = process.env.ENV_VAR;

   if(envVar) { 
      envVar // no more undefined
   }
   ```
3. [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing):
   This method can be used if you are sure the env var will always be there. The logic here is that if the env var will be the `null` or `undefined` the interpreter will take the value after the `??` operator:

   ```
   const envVar: string = process.env.ENV_VAR ?? '' // no error
   ```